# Easy way to connect tables using form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have two tables, works and artists. Every artist has multiple works. Is it possible to list those artists in a dropdown menu when creating a new work.

This is the way I solve it right now:

```
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :photo %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :exhibition_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :exhibition_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :artist_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :artist_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

The example is exactly what you're looking for.

```
collection_select(@work, :artist_id, Artist.all, :id, :name)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it should be:
collection_select(:work, :artist_id, Artist.all, :id, :name)

Comment: Depends what your object is. Next time post your complete form ;)

Comment: How can I use this method in an activeadmin form?

Comment: @polonium It's a bit more complicated. ActiveAdmin uses formtastic. It'd be something like `filter :artist, :as => :select, :collection => Hash[Artist.all.map{|a| [a.name,a.id]}]`